# Contact form 7, save selected option (dropdown menu) to database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, drop-down-menu, contact-form-7, contact-form

I am trying to save to my database, the submissions from my contact form 7 form. I found some functions (don't know the author) to do so. It works, but it won't save the option selected from the drop-down menus to the database. I don't know what I am missing. I tried this:

```
add_action("wpcf7_submit", "SE_379325_forward_cf7", 10, 2);

function SE_379325_forward_cf7($form, $result) {
 if( !class_exists('WPCF7_Submission') )
  return;
 $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
 if ($result["status"] == "mail_sent") { // proceed only if email has been sent 
  $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
  save_posted_data($posted_data);
 }
};


// your insert function:
function save_posted_data($posted_data){
$form_id = $posted_data["_wpcf7"]; // this is the post->ID of the submitted form so if you have more than one you can decide whether or not to save this form fields
if($form_id == 403)
 return;
 global $wpdb;

$wpdb->insert( 
  $wpdb->prefix.'tabletest',
  array(
    'lastname'=>$posted_data['lastName'],
    'name'=>$posted_data['firstName'],
    'email'=>$posted_data['email'],
    'phone'=>$posted_data['tel-3'],
    'subject'=>$posted_data['menu-338'],
    'role'=>$posted_data['menu-761'],
    'message'=>$posted_data['your-message'],
    'thedate'=>$posted_data['date-288']
  ),
  array('%s')
 );
}
```

The fields I cannot save are 'subject' and 'role'. They are just empty on my table columns.

[This is my form from Contact Form 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDMZ5.png)

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: First and foremost, you are placing unsanitized post data into your database. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/8255054 - secondly, can you include the hook you're using?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I thought data retrieved by Contact Form 7 was already sanitized. I will check it out. And the hook I am using is [wpcf7_submit](http://hookr.io/actions/wpcf7_submit/). Hope that can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two potential problems.

1. The form ID is probably not visible the way you're trying to get it. You can pass that to your function by getting the `$contact_form->id` in the first `submit` function.
2. The data from the dropdowns is passed as an array (always) as of a few versions ago in CF7.

I've added sanitization as well, you can alter as needed. CF7 Doesn't by default sanitize data since it's just input in/input out, and not stored anywhere.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_submit', 'SE_379325_forward_cf7', 10, 2 );
function SE_379325_forward_cf7( $form, $result ) {
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WPCF7_Submission' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( 'mail_sent' === $result['status'] ) { // proceed only if email has been sent.
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        save_posted_data( $posted_data, $form->id );
    }
}
// your insert function.
function save_posted_data( $posted_data, $form_id ) {
    if ( 403 !== $form_id ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert(
            $wpdb->prefix . 'tabletest',
            array(
                'lastname' => sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $posted_data['lastName'] ) ),
                'name'     => sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $posted_data['firstName'] ) ),
                'email'    => sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $posted_data['email'] ) ),
                'phone'    => sanitize_email( wp_unslash( $posted_data['tel-3'] ) ),
                'subject'  => sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $posted_data['menu-338'][0] ) ),
                'role'     => sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $posted_data['menu-761'][0] ) ),
                'message'  => sanitize_textarea_field( wp_unslash( $posted_data['your-message'] ) ),
                'thedate'  => sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $posted_data['date-288'] ) ),
            ),
            array( '%s' )
        );
    }
}
```